# How do I distinguish the index in a callback for an CButton array?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How do I distinguish the index in a callback for an Button array?
thx

This returns the messageBox for all indices but can't distinguish which was pressed.

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(100, ClickMe)
```

---

```
CButton *btnDelay = new CButton[4];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    (btnDelay+i)  -> Create("0", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(350, 80+i*20, 450, 100+i*20), this,100);
}
```

---

```
void CCatsGenBDlg::ClickMe()
{
    //How do I know which button was pressed ?
    MessageBox("ClickMe");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly when you create the button, give each one a unique ID e.g.

```
Create("0", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(350, 80+i*20, 450, 100+i*20), this,100+i);
```

This will give you IDs of 100 to 103

Then...

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CtomDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_COMMAND_RANGE(100, 103, OnButtonPressed)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CtomDlg::OnButtonPressed(UINT nID)
{
   //Show message box   
}
```

The ON_COMMAND_RANGE message will handle ID's in the range of your buttons and provides a way to get their specific ID in the event handler.